Django: using two related fields / foreign keys at once
I have three models:
class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.AutoField()
    team_name = models.CharField()

class Game(models.Model):
    game_id = models.AutoField()
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class TeamBoxScore(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='game_boxscore')
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='team_boxscore')
    # some stats here


What I want to do is, for every Game instance, access the TeamBoxScore that matches both the Game instance and the Team instance referenced by home_team/away_team.
Is there a way that I can have game.home_team.team_boxscore reference only the boxscore for that game_id? Or, conversely, can I specify which game.game_boxscore I want to return (the one that matches home_team or the one that matches away_team)? I want to minimize queries and avoid long iterative solutions.
I've tried annotating the fields from each TeamBoxScore instance to every Game (referencing the game_boxscore related field), but that ends up doubling the size of the queryset and placing the values from the home boxscore and the away boxscore in separate instances. I've tried going through the team_boxscore related field, but that returns every boxscore for that team (game.home_team.team_boxscore).
I've further tried to groupby these annotated values and just return the sum, but this is both inelegant and takes too long (and could be wrong!)
I've tried using a filtered queryset on Prefetch:
home_team_boxscore_prefetch = Prefetch(
        'home_team__team_boxscore',
        queryset=TeamBoxScore.objects.filter(game_id=F('game__game_id'),   team_id=F('game__home_team__team_id')),
        to_attr='home_team_boxscore'
    )

and then passing that to prefetch_related, but that ends up returning all of the home_team's home games for some reason. Any ideas? I feel like there is something very simple I'm missing.
